# Navigate with partials using rails and bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, renderpartial

I'm using rails with Bootstrap. I have a basic page with navbar along the top. What I am struggling to achieve is how to define the targets for the options in the navbar as partials beneath this navbar.

I've trawled threads on here - finding things that don't quite marry up to the above, and followed the following tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-partials ... which didn't work. No matter what I try, I end up with a link that simply directs to a whole new page.

My code as it stands (based on the above quoted tutorial)....

snippet from post_login.html.erb

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><%= link_to "P4 Sync", "p4syncpartial" %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "P4 Output", "p4outpartial" %></li>
            </ul>

<<<SNIP!!!>>>

    <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
    </div>
</body>
```

routes.rb entry for one of the above tags:

```
  match '/p4syncpartial', to: 'authentication#_perforce', via: 'get'
```

And just for completeness, my placeholder authentication/_perforce.erb:

```
<p>This is a dummy P4 partial</p>
```

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong? Thank you :)

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are trying to do - do you want to render the 'This is a dummy P4 partial' on your `post_login.html` page directly, or to create a link that points to it? If I were you I would read a bit more about rails routing as there's quite a lot of standard information that you are missing - try http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Hi Omnikron, I'm trying to render the contents of the p4 partial (and p4 output partial, and others as yet to be determined!) in the post_login... so there'll be the nav bar along the top with entries for each of the pages to be rendered in the post_login page - letting the user jump between pages as they see fit :)

Comment: It's a bit of an unusual way of doing things, and rails usually digs its heels in when you try and get creative! However this should do it: `<%= render 'authentication/perforce' %>`. You can get rid of the `link_to` (which is just a helper creating an `<a>` tag for you, [see the documentation here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)) and get rid of the `routes.rb` entry too - `render` knows where to get partial files from [automatagically!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html#method-i-render)

Comment: So I tried `<li class="active"><a><%= render 'authentication/perforce' %>P4</a></li>` - but this just rendered the content of my placeholder perforce partial within the navbar....

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that was what you were trying to do! I'm clearly not understanding the question - however I would really recommend reading the guide I posted above because I think you've got a few different things muddled. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing leading slash `/` in `link_to` `url` parameter:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><%= link_to "P4 Sync", "/p4syncpartial" %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "P4 Output", "/p4outpartial" %></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Vee, thanks for that. I added the leading slash as you suggested, but it made no difference. Can you suggest anything else?